# Putting values from GSON into TextView in android

Tags: java, android, textview, gson

I'm trying to fetch the data from a URL in GSON and putting those values into TextView. I am using `ArrayList` to add values from GSON. Here is the `AsyncTask<>` code for handling that:

```
private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CardViewExpandCollapse.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        HttpHandler httpHandler = new HttpHandler();

        String s = httpHandler.makeServiceCall(mUrl);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        AccountDetail[] accountDetails = gson.fromJson(s, AccountDetail[].class);

        ArrayList<AccountDetail> details = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(accountDetails));

        HashMap<String, String> accDetails = new HashMap<>();

        String address = details.get(0).getRow().getBillToAddress();

        Double balance = details.get(0).getRow().getTotalAccountBalance();

        Double invoices = details.get(0).getRow().getTotalOpenInvoicesValue();

        Log.e(Tag, "Response from URL " + s);

        Log.e(Tag, "Address is " + address);
        Log.e(Tag, "Balance is " + balance);
        Log.e(Tag, "Invoice is " + invoices);

        accDetails.put("billToAddress", address);
        accDetails.put("totalAccountBalance", balance + "\tUSD");
        accDetails.put("totalOpenInvoicesValue", invoices + "\tUSD");

        hashMap.add(accDetails); // size = 3

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void values) {
        super.onPostExecute(values);
        if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

        /*How can I add values from hash map to TextView here?*/

    }
}
```

In `doInBackground()` method, I am fetching the data from Gson and adding that to hash map.
In `onPostExecute()` method, I want to add values from `GSON` to `TextView`. How can I put values in `hashMap` to `TextView`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AsyncTask's doInBackground() method should return a HashMap.

Then your onPostExecute() method will receive it and should update your TextView.

Here is a code sample:

```
private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String, String>>() {
    @Override
    protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HashMap<String, String> accDetails = new HashMap<String, String>();
            //Your GSON decoding
        return accDetails ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, String> accDetails ) {
       // Display the text in your TextView i.e.
       // yourTextView.setText = accDetails.get("billToAddress");
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the exception you're seeing ?

Comment: Indeed ;) Please accept my answer if that's ok for you

Answer (score 1):

Your `doInBackground` function needs to return the `hashMap` variable to access it in `onPostExecute`.

Change `protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)`

to `protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids)`

Then make your return in that function be `return hashMap;`

Next change your `protected void onPostExecute(Void values)`

To `protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, String> hashMap)`

Finally, change your class declaration to `private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String, String>>`

Comment: If I change `protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids)` to `protected HashMap<String, String> doInBackground(Void... voids)` , then I get this error: **
`doInBackground` in my class clashes with `doInBackground` of `Android.os.AsycTask` attempting to use an incompatible return type**

Comment: Right I forgot to add that you need to change the class declaration to `private class getData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HashMap<String, String>>`

Comment: Just do `myTextView.setText(hashMap.get("MyValue"));`.